# Reading the first UVarInt of a net.Conn buffer

Tags: go, tcp, tcpserver

I have a TCP packet connection (`net.Conn`) set up by listening on a port.

```
conn, err := ln.Accept()
```

I need to read the first **UVarInt** of the `Conn.Read([]byte)` buffer, which starts at index 0.

Previously, I would only need the first byte, which is easy to do using

```
packetSize := make([]byte, 1)
conn.Read(packetSize)
// Do stuff with packetSize[0]
```

However, as previously mentioned, I need to get the first UVarInt I can reach using the net.Conn.Read() method. Keep in  mind that a UVarInt can have pretty much any length, which I cannot be sure of (the client doesn't send the size of the UVarInt). I do know however that the UVarInt starts at the very beginning of the buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the connection with a [bufio.Reader](https://godoc.org/bufio#Reader):

```
br := bufio.NewReader(conn)
```

Use the binary package to [read an unsigned varint](https://godoc.org/encoding/binary#ReadUvarInt) through the bufio.Reader:

```
n, err := binary. ReadUvarInt(br)
```

Because the bufio.Reader can buffer more than the varint, you should use the bufio.Reader for all subsequent reads on the connection.

Comment: Using NewReader(conn) indeed works, but I had to use "ReadUvarInt(br)" in order to get a proper value.

Comment: @Momo Question says varint, not uvarint. Update the question to describe your data. I'll update the answer.